# MYSQL check if value exists in either table: login script

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am trying to create a login script which checks two tables to see if the username and password exists in the database.

The purpose of having two tables is one is for suppliers/external users and the other is for internal users.

I am having difficulty with my MYSQL query where I am using NOT EXISTS. This causes the query to display the error 'ooops! username or password combination incorrect'.

can someone please show me where I am going wrong here?  thanks

```
session_start();
include("config.php");

$tbl_name="supplier_users";  
$tbl_name2="internal_users";  
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="select NOT EXISTS (select * from $tbl_name where username = {$myusername} and password = {$mypassword}) AND NOT EXISTS (select * from $tbl_name2 where username = {$myusername} and password = {$mypassword})";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

if($count==1) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user']=$myusername;
    $_SESSION['username']=$row['First_Name'];

    if(isset($_SESSION['val'])) {
        $_SESSION['val']=$_SESSION['val']+1;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['val']=1;
        header("location:../dashboard.php");
    }
} else {
    echo mysql_error();
    $_SESSION['message2'] = '<div id="message_box2"><div class="boxclose" id="boxclose" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);"></div><h23>Oooops!</h23><p>The Username and Password Combination do not match. Please try again.</p> </div>';
    header("location:../index.php");
}

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Please indent. My eyes are bleeding. And narrow your code, we don't need to see your whole program if your only problem is in the query.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL-Injection.. Also stop using mysql_* as they are deprecated, and start using mysqli_* or PDO instead.

Comment: im sorry but im really new to MySQL could you please show me how I could adapt this to mysqli and help prevent injection.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in. Any code that uses `addslashes` should receive an automatic fail on even the most cursory code review as it's obvious that's a relic from the past.

Comment: I see no good reason why you don't perform two seperate checks. Make it into a function, with the table name as an argument, and you can reuse the code.

Answer (score -1):

## Keep it simple

I see no good reason why you don't perform two seperate checks. Make it into a function, with the table name as an argument, and you can reuse the code. Something like this:

```
function getUserCount($table,$username,$password)
{
  $query = "SELECT username  
            FROM $table 
            WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  return mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

(not tested) But please look up more advice about security... if your system is meant to be really secure. Also, the mysql extension of PHP is deprecated.